# Rails StimulusJS controller not connected on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

I am using StimulusJS + Stimulus Reflex and it's all working on development. When I deploy to production (Digital Ocean) the connected() method is not fired.
The ReflexClass is performed and the ActiveRecord is updated on the server-side but the JS controller is not fired. this.stimulate() it's successfully fired because I can see the page is refreshed with new data.

Can you help me? I don't know where to look at.
I am using Cloudflare, Devise if it matters.

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus'
import StimulusReflex from 'stimulus_reflex'

export default class extends Controller {
  connect () {
    StimulusReflex.register(this)
    console.log("THIS IS CALLED ONLY ON DEVELOPMENT ENV")
  }
}
```

**view.html**

```
<div data-controller="item-group" data-id="<%=item_group.id%>" >
<%= form.check_box :state,{id: "state-#{item_group.id}", 
      data: {reflex: 'change->ItemGroup#state', "reflex-dataset": 'combined'}}, 'enabled', 'paused' %>
</div>
```

**head.html**

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>
<%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
```

**config/enviroment/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
   config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass #

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = false

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  #config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, {driver: :hiredis, url: ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" }}
  config.session_store :cache_store,
    key: "_session",
    compress: true,
    pool_size: 5,
    expire_after: 1.year
 
  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
   #config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
   #config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "amazon_#{Rails.env}"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options     = { host: 'example.com', :protocol => 'https', locale: 'en'}
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com', :protocol => 'https', locale: 'en'}
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'https://www.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true 

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false


  # Usato per Callback Advertisin Token (Url in model)
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = config.action_mailer.default_url_options
  


end
```

**config/cable.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: development

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: production
```

**app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb**

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :session_id

    def connect
      self.session_id = cookies.encrypted[:session_id]
    end
    
  end
end
```

NGNIX (managed by Coud66)

```
{% if passenger_action_cable %}
        location /cable {
            passenger_app_group_name {{ app_name }}_action_cable;
            passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
        }
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: That sounds like a general asset compilation problem. Do you precompile your assets for production, or do your assets get compiled by some buildpack or so?

Comment: compiled in production using Cloud66. I haven't any other issue with other JS functions. Only stimulus reflex

Comment: So you are sure the JS is actually compiled and included in the pack and but you see no errors on the console? I think it would be best if you could hop over to the discord, there we can help you best: https://discord.com/invite/XveN625

Comment: Yes, no other error in the console. The Reflex action is performed (active record updated) but the debug message from connected() is not called